# Identify DataPower gateway type | IBM API Connect

Tags: ibm-datapower, apiconnect

There are 2 two types of DataPower gateway as mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/api-connect/10.0.x?topic=overview-api-connect-gateway-types#reference_rww_k4s_zdb). I have installed the VMWare version provided with the installation package. How can I know whether I have "DataPower API Gateway" or "DataPower Gateway (v5 compatible)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataPower is a separate product and comes in its own "package" and version.

When you install/setup API Connect you can chose which version of API Connect configuration on the DataPower instance you want.

The v5 compatibility is only for older DataPower appliances (XB62, XI50, etc) and since you are using VMware, just install the latest DataPower version and then use the API Gateway version.

Comment: So, It means that I have the DataPower Gateway VMware version which supports both the API Gateway mode and v5 compatibility mode and it depends on how I configure it. Did I get it right?

Comment: Basically, yes, but it depends on the Firmware version of the DataPower instance... If you upgrade it to 2018.1.x you are able to run either or gateway